# How to generate confusion matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I have a school projects with deep learning face recognition. I need reciprocal matrix to measure performance metrics like accuracy, precision. I tried the following codes for this. However, the y_test parameter gives an error. How can I solve this?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(img_array, img_labels,
                                                    shuffle=True, stratify=img_labels,
                                                    test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

print('Eğitim için eleman sayısı, yükseklik/genişlik ve kanal sayısı: ', x_train.shape)
print('Test için eleman sayısı, yükseklik/genişlik ve kanal sayısı: : ',x_test.shape)

print('Eğitimdeki örnek ve sınıf sayısı :', y_train.shape) 
print('Testteki örnek ve sınıf sayısı : ',y_test.shape)
```

my code

```
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [55], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
      2 print(cm)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:307, in confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels, sample_weight, normalize)
    222 def confusion_matrix(
    223     y_true, y_pred, *, labels=None, sample_weight=None, normalize=None
    224 ):
    225     """Compute confusion matrix to evaluate the accuracy of a classification.
    226 
    227     By definition a confusion matrix :math:`C` is such that :math:`C_{i, j}`
   (...)
    305     (0, 2, 1, 1)
    306     """
--> 307     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    308     if y_type not in ("binary", "multiclass"):
    309         raise ValueError("%s is not supported" % y_type)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:93, in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     90     y_type = {"multiclass"}
     92 if len(y_type) > 1:
---> 93     raise ValueError(
     94         "Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} and {1} targets".format(
     95             type_true, type_pred
     96         )
     97     )
     99 # We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no more needed
    100 y_type = y_type.pop()

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets
```

Comment: Can you give sample distinct values of `y_test, y_pred` ?
Values might be continuous values.
For Classification , the values will not continuous

Comment: From the error log, I would suspect that your model return a set of probability for each class (e.g. `(0.7,0.3)` for two classes), while your `y` variable contains the class labels.
In this case you, you should have a 2D array of shape `(n_samples, n_classes)` as output of your model when predicting, you can get the class label by selecting the argmax of each row.

Answer (score 0):

I know I should not be providing this in the answer but am not able to add comments right now.
The classification report expects both the y_pred and y_test to be a 1-D array with class labels as integers.
The prediction of the TensorFlow model is mostly a 2D array with each entry being 1D array with class probability for a given row. So, you need to do some preprocessing on the y_pred.
I came across something similar a few weeks ago, I am gonna share a few lines of codes that may be helpful.

```
    res = np.array(res)
    res = res.flatten()
    res = np.round(res)
```

Please note that the above code is for binary classification. For multilabel classification, you may use `np.argmax`.